# Is there a way to select the formula above the first empty cell and paste downwards till the last full cell?

Tags: excel, vba

In this formula:

```
With Intersect(wsDAO.UsedRange, wsDAO.Columns("R"))
            .AutoFilter 1, "<>Same"
            With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("B:O"))
                .Copy wsDAR.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .EntireRow.Delete
            End With
            .AutoFilter
        End With
```

It allows me to take cells from wsDAO in column R, with any other word but the word "Same" puts a copy over to another page 'wsDAR' and deletes the original.

What I'd like to do, and I'm not sure where to start, but what I was thinking is using this part of the script:

```
lastrow = wsDAO.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("B"))
     .Copy wsDAO.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With
```

And use it where in I have a cell in the formula above and copy it down till the last row with data in it.

I just don't know where to start, I figured if I copied the data from another cell but that wouldn't work because of the '.Copy' would override anything saved.

Can someone help me with this? I know I'm a few lines from solving my issues, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample file, you want to copy the formula in I1 to any empty cell in column I. The following code line should do this:

```
lastrow = wsDAO.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

wsDAO.Range("I1:I" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 _
    = wsDAO.Cells(1, "I").FormulaR1C1
```

Comment: That would just copy the cell downwards, and not change the value of the formula. Already thought of that :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to copy and where. A sample file or layout would be helpful at this stage.